# XGBoostError: Unicode-3 is not supported

Tags: python, xgboost, streamlit, xgbclassifier

I am trying to load an XGBClassifier in my streamlit app from a pickle file.

When I load it and try to predict on the new input values, it throws the error:

```
XGBoostError: [11:25:40] c:\users\administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.6.0\src\data\array_interface.h:462: Unicode-3 is not supported.
```

The entire traceback is:

```
2022-07-02 11:25:40.046 Uncaught app exception 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "temp.py", line 250, in <module>        
    st.write(clf.predict(feat_list))
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1434, in predict
    class_probs = super().predict(
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1049, in predict
    predts = self.get_booster().inplace_predict(
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 2102, in inplace_predict
    _check_call(
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 203, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [11:25:40] c:\users\administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.6.0\src\data\array_interface.h:462: Unicode-3 
is not supported.
```

I load the model this way:

```
clf = pickle.load(open('xgb.pkl', "rb"))
```

Or

```
clf = xgboost.XGBClassifier(tree_method ="hist", enable_categorical=True) 
clf.load_model("model.json")
```

And I predict using:

```
clf.predict(feat_list)
```

Comment: Does your app runs properly without using streamlit?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which came along with the the same XGBoostError. In my case the reason was the `dtype` of `ndarray`, which was supposed to be `object`.

Assuming that your `feat_list` is `numpy.ndarray` and that you create it in such way:

```
feat_list = np.array(features)
```

adding `dtype=object`:

```
feat_list = np.array(features, dtype=object)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This fixed my issue with the Unicode-3 error also.

Answer (score 0):

Encode text as UTF-8 with error handling but while you might run into string error as well since XGBoost requires the output variables to be numeric. So you might need to address this as well and with the pickle file remember to load the model and the vectorizer too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).