# XGBoostError : Unicode-3 is not supported

Tags: deployment, pycharm, xgboost, streamlit

[XGBoostError:Unicode-3 is not Supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqkCS.png)

Comment: Hi, @Vaibhav Parinche, you should add the error as text as well as the code that produced it. It makes it wayyyy easier for people to understand the problem and help you fix it. :)

Comment: Maybe my answer to the question with similar title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836857/xgboosterror-unicode-3-is-not-supported can be helpful?