# XGBoostError in python while load the model.pkl file (Unicode-1 is not supported.)

Tags: python, django-models, unicode, model, xgboost

i fount this error can anyone help me
XGBoostError at /result/
[22:06:55] C:\buildkite-agent\builds\buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-0750514818a16474a-1\xgboost\xgboost-ci-windows\src\data\array_interface.h:492: Unicode-1 is not supported.

XGBoostError at /result/
[22:06:55] C:\buildkite-agent\builds\buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-0750514818a16474a-1\xgboost\xgboost-ci-windows\src\data\array_interface.h:492: Unicode-1 is not supported.

can anyone know how to solve this error?
this error is new to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Probably it's because of some datatype format in one of the array records. Please. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836857/xgboosterror-unicode-3-is-not-supported and add the type object to your array transformation.